# Using custom connector in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**My Issues:**

1. Create new logic app custom connector by uploading a swagger file. No authentication is selected. Connect via on premise gateway option is checked. API to be called by the connector is hosted on a VM and uses no authentication.
2. Create a logic app and add the custom connector.
3. Running the logic app gives the following error:

   `{
     "status": 400,
     "message": "Header 'x-ms-apim-tokens' not found.\r\nclientRequestId: dc6.........",
     "source": "gatewayconnector-australiasoutheast.logic-ase-australiasoutheast.p.azurewebsites.net"
   }`

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a regression that made its way to a few Logic Apps geo-regions earlier this week. All regions should receive a patched build by end-of-day Tuesday 4/17.

Once the patch is deployed, you would need to update the custom connector (there is no need to update/recreate any connections)

Comment: The patch has been deployed to Australia SouthEast region as of 2018-04-13 18:00PST

Comment: That works now! However, now facing an issue with the "Http with AAD" connector. This used to work fine. Im getting a 400 with the following body: {
  "$content-type": "application/octet-stream",
  "$content": "QmFzZVFz........}

Comment: hard to tell what is the underlying issue without more context. what you are seeing is binary content attached as a property on a json (hence the wrapper object with $content and $content-type properties). This would not be related to AAD. Could be due to a change in your swagger.